# Responsive design images not scaling

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm learning HTML/CSS in my web standards design course this month and this week we are fixing our websites to be responsive.

I have converted all of my px to percentages and all font from px to em. I messed something up with the max-width: 100% on my gallery.

I'll post my link instead of all the codes.

http://jgoldd.github.io/wsd/index.html

Comment: Btw, the site was suppose to be 100% but they require us to follow some design rules, can't really do anything I want.  Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Take the width and margin off your body tag. Make a class called a wrapper and add it inside your containers eg

```
.wrapper{
   max-width:960px;
   margin:0 auto;
   width:100%;
}

<header>
     <div class="wrapper">
         // put your content in here
     </div>
</header>

<div id="content">
    <div class="wrapper">
        // put your content in here
    </div>
</div>

<footer>
     <div class="wrapper">
         // put your content in here
     </div>
</footer>
```

If you don't want to do this you could just set your body to

```
body{
  max-width:960px;
  width:100%;
}
```

But I would change your structure to the way with a wrapper is good to practice clean code hygiene from the start :-)

Comment: Added wrapper to all my elements and added the class to the css and it still wont resize :/

Comment: I see, looking at those images you would want to put a media query in to make the #gallery_container and the images inside width 100%

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to play with it a bit, but here is a quick bit to get you going in the right direction. (remove the lines I commented with REMOVE)

```
#gallery li{
     width: 49%;
     display: inline-block;
     .display: inline;  /* for IE 8 */
     zoom: 1; /* for IE 8 */
     /* float: left; REMOVE */
}

#gallery img {
    width: 100%;
    /* max-width: 100%; REMOVE */
}

#gallery_container{
    width: 100%;
    /* width: 41.666667%;  REMOVE */
}
```

Give it a try. Should give you better results and hopefully get you where you want to be.

Answer (score 0):

Your css is too buggy. So, let me explain you a simple technique to activate responsive behavior to images

Try this code in HTML

```
<img class="resize" src="http://jgoldd.github.io/wsd/images/mountains1.jpg">
```

CSS

```
.resize {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}
```

This code simple activates the responsive behavior on images.

Do let me know if you have any queries...! :)